# How to install Node.js packages from Git repository inside specific folders

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, npm

I am aware of how to install from Git, my question is different:

I have a repository structured somewhat like this :

```
project
--packages
  --moduleA
    --dist
      --index.js
      --package.json
    --src
      --index.mjs
    --package.json
  --moduleB
    --dist
      --index.js
      --package.json
    --src
      --index.mjs
    --package.json
```

And I want to know if it's possible to install both `moduleA` and `moduleB` using the same Git repository, *and* isntalling both from their respective `dist` directory. In other words, if their respective `package.json` declare their module names as `@company/moduleA` and `@company/moduleB`, then I want my `node_modules` to look like

```
node_modules
--@company
  --moduleA
    --index.js
    --package.json
  --moduleB
    --index.js
    --package.json
```

Is this possible using either `npm` or `yarn`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have currently settled with [gitpkg](https://github.com/ramasilveyra/gitpkg) and [yarn](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn) has package manager.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You can use [napa](https://www.npmjs.com/package/napa) for that.

add this to your `package.json`. you can use the folder name as key in `napa` object.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "install-from-github": "napa"
  },
  "napa": {
    "install_as_foo": "username/repo",
    "install_as_bar": "git@example.com:user/repo"
  }
}
```

run `npm run install-from-github` to run napa; or just do `npx napa`

actual complete example: this will insttall noop2 repo under `@company/test1` and `@company/test2`

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "napa": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "install-from-github": "napa"
  },
  "napa": {
    "@company/test1": "yoshuawuyts/noop2",
    "@company/test2": "yoshuawuyts/noop2"
  }
}
```

output

[image]

Comment: I read the doc, and then your example, and I'm not entirely certain how to write this inside my `package.json`; could you add how to apply the config using the question's snippet as base? Thanks.

Comment: Updated answer with complete example

Comment: I'm sorry, this does not work. It puts the entire repository inside node modules, and does not fetch the specific `dist` folder of each modules. In fact, your updated example assumes two repositories, which is not what the question asks. If I wanted that feature, I'd be using `yarn`, because `napa` does not even update the `package-lock.js` file. Sorry.